# Paypal Express Checkout not Showing the Order summery

Tags: php, zend-framework2, paypal, payum

I am using the Paypal Express checkout in zend framework payments are working fine but there is an issues with the order summery on paypal checkout page.

It is not showing any order information there.

Here is my controller:

```
$storage = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('payum')->getStorage('Reisesparer\Model\PaymentDetails');

$details = $storage->create();
$details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = 'EUR';
$details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = $request->getPost('grandtotal_price');
$details['ORDER_CUSTOM_ID'] = $orderNumber;
$storage->update($details);
$captureToken =    this->getServiceLocator()->get('payum.security.token_factory')->createCaptureToken(               this->redirect()->toUrl($captureToken->getTargetUrl().'?amout='.$details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT']);
```

[image]

How i can show the current transaction summery on the checkout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide item details in the same way as you provided currency etc. But you have to be careful while setting up details about items, specially about the total price, item numbers etc. Because they should be in sequential orders and calculated exactly.

```
$details['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'] = 'Book One';
$details['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1'] = 'Book Two';
$details['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'] = 25.00;
$details['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1'] = '22.00';
$details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'] = 47.00;
```

You must read the [Doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) for paypal express checkout to make it implement. For item details, search for **Payment Details Item Type Fields** on that doc page.

You can check this [issue](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/issues/77) on order summary too.

Hope it helps you!